# How to create a shopify app dev environment

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I'm building an embedded shopify app and I struggle to test it as embedded app because it's veeeery slow. I started my app following the official guide of creating an app with node & nextjs and I'm still using both but i'm considering getting rid of nextjs and using just react since it feels veeery slow and so heavy for ngrok to transfer all the files to the shopify iframe...

What would you recommend to work smoothly with shopify when building an embedded app?

(I'm mostly working locally but I still need to often go check that it works well inside the admin & to use shopify-app-bridge library)

Answer (score 0):

if ngrok is slow for you, i would suggest [heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) for deployment and testing,
create new application at heroku, you can also connect it with your github and use automatic deploy when you push your code

Comment: I am working with Heroku but every time it is deploying after a small change. Is there any option  available to test it staging. I want to test it in local first then will update to heroku.